# Hide elements over a specific one in a list in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a (possibly) long list of elements and each of them has a weight attached.

I have to show in a vue component only the first elements of the list and hide the others over a button "Show more" but the number of elements i have to show depends on the weight.

If the first elements have weights over 100, i have to show only those with over 100 (don't matter how many they are) and hide the others. If no elements with over 100 weight is present in the list, i have to show only the first 5 elements.

I have prepared a [sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-voice-njb70?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue) with 2 list of elements as example of the two possible behaviour. How can i achieve this result? Thanks

EDIT: the first idea i had is to preparse the list and split in two list: a show list and a hide list. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand correctly what you are trying to achieve, but something like this ? I've adapted your sandbox: [adapted sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-newton-gj4iq?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue)

If the first item has a weight of more than 100 in the list, then only the items with weight over 100 from the list will be displayed.
If there are no items with a weight of over 100, then only the first 5 items are displayed.

Let me know if this isn't what you want and we can work on it ;)

Comment: You're on the right way. Just 2 things: the whole `<li>` element have to disappear, not only the content, and this is a problem since vue doesn't want `v-if` and `v-for` in the same element. Second thing I need a button to show hidden elements.

Comment: ok so if you check again I think now the filtering works as desired right? And I've added a button that can show all elements. So yes, the only way to achieve what you want with vue in this case is to alter the collection you are iterating on

Comment: Very nice and elegant solution, i like it. Thanks.

Comment: glad I could help ;)